# Android: Difference between System Service and Service of a System Application

Tags: android, android-service, system-services

I build my own Android and have to create a service. See the question in the title.

What i know so far:

- Both approaches should have the same permissions, because they run under system privileges
- In case of the system service i have to do more adjustments in the AOSP code, whereas i just need to add my application to the system apps for the second approach
- To use the service i just need to get the system service using getSystemService(...) on the Context object, whereas i need to bind to the application service in the second approach

Questions:

- Am I right with the assumption that the privileges for both approaches are the same?
- Is there a soft reboot for system applications on failure? (as like it's the case for the system service)
- Which other differences exist?

Thanks in advance